# How to implement the shear_random method

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

This is my code, how do I implement the shear_random method, where is the tensor input for value x?
I tried to put my data set , not working .
I tried to put my input shape , not working .
Where is that tensor input ?

```
 model = Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(),
  keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.1),
  #layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

This is how i load my image into dataset .

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory
```

This error appear :     h, w = x.shape[row_axis], x.shape[col_axis]
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'

when i try to do it like this

```
keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(x=train_dataset , intensity = 0.0101),
```